# LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 clear alpha not working in multi-script project

Tags: c++, direct3d

I've created a Direct3D Device and have a render loop that starts with clearing the window to transparent red using the following code:

```
d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(100, 255, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
```

This works perfectly, but only when it's created in the entry point script for some reason. When trying to do the exact same thing in a different script and creating the Direct3D window inside a function called by my entry point script's WinMain, the alpha channel of the Direct3D fails and it shows plain red. The WindowProc functions are both the same for the single-script Direct3D window and the multiple-scripts one.

I hope there are some thing I could check without the need of posting the code here, but if needed I am able to create minimal versions of the two to post.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "script"? What exactly is the difference between when this works and doesn't work? `Clear` sets every pixel of the back buffer to the colour, it doesn't alpha blend the colour, so it's not obvious why you wouldn't always just see plain red.

Comment: The other script is a static class within the same namespace. I don't know how, but the alpha channel does work for me when creating the DirectX layer in the entry-point script.